# Скрыть часть информации под ссылкой

Tags: php

На странице имеется куча форм для выбора жанра песен. Жанров много, потому листать все эти формы для  довольно долго. Как можно сделать, чтобы часть форм выводилась на экран(например первые 10), а остальные были скрыты под ссылкой и выводились только по нажатию на ссылку ? Возник такой вопрос, потому что формы создаются циклом и не знаю, как указать, что нужно показывать только определенное количество форм.
Часть кода отвечающая за создание форм:

```
$genre = mysql_query("SELECT `Название` FROM `janri` ORDER BY `Название`");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($genre)){
echo '<div id="spisok_janrov"><form method="POST" action="music.php"><input type="submit" name="genre" value="' . $row['Название'] . '" /></form><br></div>';
}
```

Comment: Вы бы добавили немного исходного кода, чтобы было от чего отталкиваться. Т.к. вариантов много. 
Выводите 10, остальные выводите скрытыми и выводите кнопку, по нажатию на которую остальные становятся видимыми. Либо по скролу постепенно показываете остальные.

Comment: Прошу прощения, щас скину.

Comment: Ну а как это сделать, если они все в цикле находятся ? Как указать, чтоб он вывел только 10 ?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Считать итерации в цикле. После определённого значения `$maxCount` остальные формы прячем. Показываем кнопку чтобы показать остальные формы.

`<div id="spisok_janrov">`
id кстати должны быть уникальными на странице

Если jquery подключен, например так:

```
$genre = mysql_query("SELECT `Название` FROM `janri` ORDER BY `Название`");
$maxCount = 10;
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($genre)) {
    $i++;
    echo '<div class="spisok_janrov"><form method="POST" '.($i > $maxCount ? 'style="display:none;"' : '') . ' action="music.php"><input type="submit" name="genre" value="' . $row['Название'] . '" /></form><br></div>';
    if ($i == $maxCount + 1) {
        echo '<input type="button" id="show_other" onclick="$(\".spisok_janrov form\").show();" value="Show other">';
        echo '<a href="#" id="show_other" onclick="$(\".spisok_janrov form\").show(); return false;">Show other';
    }
}
```

Ещё js лучше отдельно выносить от html, вместо onclick атрибутов:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#show_other').click(function() {
        $('.spisok_janrov form').show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: @Андрей если ответ является решением, его можно пометить галочкой

Comment: Вставил ваш код, формы скрылись, но по нажатию на кнопку они не выводятся. Jquery подключен.

Answer (score 0):

```
$genre = mysql_query("SELECT `Название` FROM `janri` ORDER BY `Название`");
$myCounter = 0;/*инициализируем счетчик*/
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($genre)){
if($myCounter == 10) echo('<div class="under-button">');/*больше десяти в div*/
echo '<div id="spisok_janrov<?php echo("_". $myCounter) ?>"><form method="POST" action="music.php"><input type="submit" name="genre" value="' . $row['Название'] . '" /></form><br></div>';
$myCounter++;/**/
}
if($myCounter >= 10) echo('</div>');/*больше десяти в div*/
```

Класс under-button определить в css в необходимом стиле, обратить внимание, что id элементов на странице должны быть уникальными.